# Make TextBox text disappear after mouse click

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to C# so this is my first task essentially, I'm hoping to make a simple login page.
I would like the text to disappear from the textbox once it has been clicked, here's what I have tried so far;

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    bool hasBeenClicked = false;

    private void textBox1_Focus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox box = sender as TextBox;
        box.Text = string.Empty;
        hasBeenClicked = true;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

This is from a similar post on here, It doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is something else I have tried;

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   
    private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

I understand it may be a silly mistake, I'm learning.
Any helps is massively appreciated :)
I'm using Winforms

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text. And please add a tag specifying the UI framework you use (WPF, WinForms, Xamarin, UWP, ASP.NET, Unity, ...).

Comment: What is `TextBox_Focus()`? What does it handle? Did you add this handler manually? Did you subscribe to some event? Which one? -- As mentioned, remove the images and paste in your code as text (isn't that simpler?).

Comment: Regarding Arthur Edgarov's comment: If the default technology in a company is Winforms, then it makes sense to learn it.
I do not agree, then once you've lerned WPF, you will learn Winforms. But technologies are quite different in their philosophy.

Comment: Use the Enter event, [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-add-an-event-handler?view=netdesktop-6.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the event MouseClick on the TextBox:

```
private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

In your screenshot, you are missing a reference. Click into the textbox events and add it like so:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both of which should probably work but you've got to link the event to the function. You can either do this in the Designer or in code. For the Mouse click variant to work and link the event in code you can add the following in the constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MouseClick += textbox1_MouseClick;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Add Event Handler

You have not linked the given methods with the event, as you can see **0 refereces** for both functions. You can add a mouse Click event as:

```
textBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(textbox1_Mouseclick);
```

Similarly, you have to add event if you want to do with the focus event.